# show/hide div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, one is hidden and the other one is visible. I'm using css `display:none;` to hide first and using `style.display="block";`
when I refresh the page it gives same div name in the address bar but the div is hidden.
I just want the div to stay block after refreshing or submitting the form inside the div

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sample</title>
<style>
#content {
    flex:8;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-basis:100%;
    padding:0 10px 0x 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
#leftnav {
    flex:1;
    padding-top:20px;   
}
#midcontent {
    flex:9;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    display:block;
}
#leftnav ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#m1,#m2,#m3 {
    flex:9; 
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftnav" align="center">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#m1" onClick="div1()">Page m1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#m2" onClick="div2()">Page m2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#m3" onClick="div3()">Page m3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="midcontent" align="center">
    <p>Home Page</p>
    </div>
    <div id="m1" align="center">
    <p>Div m1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="m2" align="center">
    <p>Div m2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="m3" align="center">
    <p>Div m3</p>
    </div>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var d=document.getElementById('midcontent');
var d1=document.getElementById('m1');
var d2=document.getElementById('m2');
var d3=document.getElementById('m3');   

function div1() {
    if(d.style.display === "block") {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "block";
        d2.style.display = "none";
        d3.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function div2() {
    if(d.style.display === "block") {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "none";
        d2.style.display = "block";
        d3.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function div3() {
    if(d.style.display === "block") {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d3.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "none";
        d2.style.display = "none";
        d3.style.display = "block";
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Refresh problem aside, why are you using if {} else {} if you are doing the exact same thing at the end no matter what?

Comment: Yes, when you refresh a webpage all state is lost, you need to store your state somewhere persistent to remain during a refresh.

Comment: *"i just want the div to stay block after refreshing"* - If you want to persist information from one page load to another then you need to store that information outside of the page.  Possibly in local storage, a cookie, server-side, etc.

Comment: _“when i refresh the page it give same div name in the address bar”_ - explain what you actually mean by that. I am assuming that you are referring to the ID of some element appearing as the hash/fragment? Then you should show us your code that achieves that in the first place. Provide a [mre] that illustrates the whole issue, not just some script snippet without much context.

Comment: i have given a full example, when i refresh it goes to home page while i need the current div to stay shown

Comment: You _haven't_ given a full example. As 04FS implied, you mentioned the div being in the URL, but I see no indication of how you're retrieving or using that.

Comment: Hello, please use the stackoverflow function and show us an output of the code so that we can help you better and more clearly
I did not understand your meaning correctly

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
function div1() {
    var d=document.getElementById('midcontent');
    var d1=document.getElementById('m1');
    if(d.style.display === "block") {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        d.style.display = "none";
        d1.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

to:

```
function toggleDiv() {
   document.getElementById('midcontent').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('m1').style.display = "block";
}
```

"i just want the div to stay block after refreshing" call the function on page load in html to make it execute after refresh of page:

```
<body onLoad="toggleDiv()">
  <!-- Your html content -->
</body>
```

alternatively you can also do it in js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    toggleDiv()
});
```

If you want more in depth persistance and/or variable changes please provide additional information on how and why you want to do this exactly!

Comment: Your onload handler can't function without input data. This doesn't really answer the question. Apparently the OP wants to parse the URL for said data.

Comment: The question since then has been editied numerous times. When initially posted all I could decypher was he wants on page refresh the divs to toggle in this fashion after the DOM is ready,  which I have provided him with an answer. As I also ended my answer with "If you want more in depth persistance and/or variable changes please provide additional information " So the OP can provide some more information. We really can't read his mind here. If he wants to parse a URL, and use it, no problem. But he needs to state that and give us info on params etc. :)