# show/hide div using javascript and keep the hidden div block after running javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, one is hidden and the other one is visible. I'm using css display:none; to hide first and using style.display="block"; when I refresh the page it gives same div name in the address bar but the div is hidden. I just want the div to stay block after refreshing or submitting the form inside the div

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
    <style>
    #content {
        flex:8;
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        justify-content:space-between;
        flex-basis:100%;
        padding:0 10px 0x 10px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #leftnav {
        flex:1;
        padding-top:20px;   
    }
    #midcontent {
        flex:9;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:20px;
        display:block;
    }
    #leftnav ul {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #m1,#m2,#m3 {
        flex:9; 
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:20px;
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftnav" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#m1" onClick="div1()">Page m1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#m2" onClick="div2()">Page m2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#m3" onClick="div3()">Page m3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="midcontent" align="center">
        <p>Home Page</p>
        </div>
        <div id="m1" align="center">
        <p>Div m1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="m2" align="center">
        <p>Div m2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="m3" align="center">
        <p>Div m3</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var d=document.getElementById('midcontent');
    var d1=document.getElementById('m1');
    var d2=document.getElementById('m2');
    var d3=document.getElementById('m3');   
    
    function div1() {
        if(d.style.display === "block") {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d1.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d1.style.display = "block";
            d2.style.display = "none";
            d3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function div2() {
        if(d.style.display === "block") {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d1.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "block";
            d3.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    function div3() {
        if(d.style.display === "block") {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d3.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d.style.display = "none";
            d1.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "none";
            d3.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You already asked this question yesterday and got answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859436/show-hide-div-using-javascript

Comment: So you want to store the state of the page so you can load it according the next time, you have to set and read a cookie.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show/hide div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859436/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: nothing worked, i have tried all answers thats why im asking again